# Referential integrity access

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, referential-integrity

I have two tables in access database. First table is named Program, its fields are Program ID and Program Name, the Program ID is the primary key for this table. The second table is named Partner, its fields are Partner ID and Partner Name, the Partner ID is the primary key for the Partner table. I have another table, which is an intersection table, which shows all the connections between the program and the partner tables. The intersection table has the fields Program ID, Program Name, Partner ID and Partner Name. I have a one-many relationship between the program table and the intersection table and a one - many relationship between the partner table and the intersection table. I also have the referential integrity selected on both these relationships (both update and delete selected). My problem is : If I make any changes to the Program Name in the program table then I want the change to be updated into the intersection tables Program Name field also. Similarly for the Partner Name field. I am unable to do this. I tried adding the Program Name field to the existing relation ship on the Program ID between the program and the intersection table, but access does not allow me to enforce referential integrity, it gives error: "No unique index for the referenced field in the primary table". I have also tried creating a Unique index on the Program Name field (not primary key). Can anyone please advice me some options.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intersection table should **not** include the Program/Partner **Names** at all, it should only include the Program/Partner **ID** values.

By keeping a copy of the names in the intersection table you have *denormalized* your data. This is generally considered to be a "Bad Thing".

Comment: Ok, I think I can remove the name fields from the intersection table. But just to answer my question, is there a way to update the program name field in the intersection table if they are changed in the program table. If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: @Ksagar If you *really* want to keep the current (bad) design you might be able to create a unique index on both the [ProgramID] and [ProgramName] fields, then update the Relationship to include both of those fields. I just tried a very simple setup and it seems to have worked for me, but I strongly suggest that you do NOT keep the Program/Partner names in the intersection table.